# Which model six-core Xeon processor does the new highest-end Mac Pro have?

Tags: mac, cpu, multi-core, xeon

Apple announced a new Mac Pro with up to 12 cores, and I'm having trouble finding the exact specifications of the six-core Xeon processor inside it.

I'm in charge of sourcing a few of these computers for a certain someone who's a bit of a technology nerd... Telling him it's the "most expensive" probably won't cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fine print under [these benchmark results](http://www.apple.com/macpro/features/processor.html) refers to "preproduction Mac Pro 12-core 2.93GHz units," so I would say [Xeon X5670](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/products/server/processor/xeon5000/specifications).

Comment: They're pricey.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Huh. My sleuthing was a waste of time. ;-) [Apple's Press Release](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/07/27macpro.html) has the straight dope.

It indeed maxes out at two 2.93 GHz 6-core Intel Xeon X5670 processors (12-cores). Base configurations are one W3530 (BTO upgrade to W3565 or W3680) or two E5620 (BTO upgrade to X5650 or X5670).

Since the base 8-core model with E5620 processors starts at $3499 (US), and Intel sells the X5670 for over $1000 more, each, I'd be stunned to see a price less than $4999 on that bad boy. Apple *might* get a better deal for the X5670, but they will also add some margin.